# CSS disappears when I add a doctype

Tags: css, nginx, doctype

When I add a doctype to my site, my CSS fails to load. It works fine when there is no doctype.

This is my doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

My CSS location is here:

```
www.site.com/static/css/main.css
```

Defined like this:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I did some googling, but my site pretty much validates, so I cant understand why the entire CSS would refuse to show completely!

Here is a URL: [LIVE SITE](http://shoutkey.com/impression)

I am using latest Google Chrome

Comment: Have you tried the <!DOCTYPE html> doctype instead? Without seeing html or css, it's the first thing I'd be eliminating as a dead-end (or determining to be the solution)

Comment: Please give precisions about the browser(s) you're having the problem with

Comment: Added a link to live site in description

Comment: Your code works locally on my pc with firefox. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510274/doctype-css-problem for a similar problem. Check whether your server sends the css file with the right MIME type `text/css`.

Comment: @JamesWillson (1) Just use `<!doctype html>` - there is no need for that long doctype; (2) try `href="static/css/main.css"`; (3) you don't need a `type` attribute on the LINK element if you're loading an external resource; (4) you don't need that ` /` at the end of the LINK element. So: `<link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: <!doctype html> doesnt work. I tried removing the type and that also had no effect :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [21:51:53.698] The stylesheet /static/css/main.css was not loaded
>   because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".

You need to make sure the mime type is `text/css`.

Comment: Thank you so much. How do I set the mime type? Is this a server issue?

Comment: Yes.  It depends on the server.  What server is it?

Comment: Where did you read that message?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Firefox - error console :)

Comment: @JamesWillson See http://www.softmodal.com/blog/2010/10/adding-a-mime-type-to-nginx/

Comment: @LeeKowalkowski The `Ctrl + Shift + K` console? Wow! My Firebug gave me nothing, but that console does give that message. I had no idea that the built-in console can be useful.

Comment: Yeah, Firebug is a little tired these days, the built in stuff is getting much better - in all browsers.

Comment: The mime-type of CSS message/behaviour has been in Firefox ever since I can remember.  I didn't know it happens in Chrome sensitive to the DOCTYPE though, so +1 to the question for that.

Comment: Is this assuming that default nginx doesnt already have the text/css mime defined as css. Im going to look now, but surely that isnt the case??

Comment: @James Willson: Yeah, sounds a little weird, but according to http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#types, that appears to be true.  I've never heard of nginx before, looks like it's designed to be fast, so the defaults are probably bare-minimum (I actually have no idea).

Comment: This is the second line of my config. So it is already being defined :(
 
text/css  css;

Comment: @James Willson: Hmm, are you missing a semi-colon or anything (on the line before)?  Because http://web-sniffer.net/ says your serving it as text/plain (as does Firefox).

Comment: @JamesWillson could you post your `nginx.conf` file. Maybe you have unintendendly commented out the line `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` by changing it to (C-like) `#include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` in this file.

Comment: I just got my css validated and still not fixed! Congratulations! No Error Found.

Comment: I dont have the include mime.types line! I will add it and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JamesWillson See http://wiki.brightbox.co.uk/docs:nginx for an example where to put the line

Comment: Right, no luck, still! After moving the config to the server and restarting nginx. I have done the following. Checked the location of the mime  type file (mine is here: /opt/conf/mime.types). Then I added it to my app-nginx.conf right below http so it is like this: http { include /opt/conf/mime.types;

Comment: My nginx is slightly out dated. I am going to put the newest version on there because this seems like a bug.

Comment: I dont have this working yet, but you have highlighted the problem, so I think you deserve the answer. Thank you also to Halex.

Comment: Fixed!! Thank you for sorting out my configs. That in conjunction with the updated nginx fixed it.